# Get a Objectmember from a cell

Tags: vba, excel

I want to create diagramms dynamically and encounter a problem her.

Usually (static) I use

> Selection.Position = xlLabelPositionBelow

and everything works. Now I want to get the member from a cell like

> Selection.Position = Range("H18").Value2

Where I have just written xlLabelPostionBelow into H18.

But now I get a `RuntimeError: 438: Object does not support the Method`.

I just do not know what to do. My guess was that I cannot use "xlLabelPostionBelow" as a string but I cannot find out whether it is of another type or not.

Comment: xlLabelPostionBelow is a symbol that represents a number not a string.  Oddly though that symbol cannot be found in my Object Browser.  Ah you have a typo!!

Comment: Do you know what number represents what position? Checking msdn I cannot find it https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.xldatalabelposition.aspx

Comment: Check spelling of said symbol please.   xlLabelPositionBelow vs xlLabelPostionBelow , you dropped an i.  And the correct symbol resolves to number 1.

Comment: The value of `xlLabelPositionBelow` is 1, check this link of MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193036.aspx

Comment: Easiest way to find the number is to type `?xlLabelPositionBelow` into the immediate window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think we answered your question in the comments.  You want to put some values on a sheet to influence your code.

OK, one can use Names for constants as well as Ranges, so we can define a constant and refer to it later

```
Option Explicit

Sub DefineMySymbol_RunOnce()
    Sheet1.Names.Add "xlLabelPositionBelow", 1
    Sheet1.Range("H18").Value2 = "xlLabelPositionBelow"  '* this is just a string


End Sub

Sub UsingValueFromSheet()

    '* here we will pull out the constant (1) and cast to a variable
    Dim eDataLabelPosition As Excel.XlDataLabelPosition
    eDataLabelPosition = CLng(Split(Sheet1.Names.Item(Sheet1.Range("H18").Value2).RefersTo, "=")(1))

    '* eDataLabelPosition should now appear in Locals Window as xlLabelPositionBelow
    Stop

    '* and now you can set you Position
    'Selection.Position = eDataLabelPosition

End Sub
```